# How can I refer to a variable from a string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm coding a text-based adventure game for my python project in school, and I'm currently creating a fight function. It involves a lot of dictionaries, hence why I need to refer to a variable from a string. Here is an example of what I am asking!

```
some_dict = {
 'one':1,
 'two':2
 }
x = 'some_dict'
print(x)
print(x['one'])
```

I want it to print the dictionary dict, not the string 'dict'. Then on the second print, I would want it to print the value in 'one', from the dictionary dict. Is there some function that can convert the string to a variable some how or check for a variable matching the string? Or something along those lines? Thank you so much!

Comment: _It involves a lot of dictionaries_ - who about putting those dictionaries in an outer `dict` using is name as key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems with naming a variable after a [builtin type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) in Python:**

```py
# this will pass
myDict = dict()

dict = {
 'one': 1,
 'two': 2
}

# this will *not* pass!
myDict = dict()

# nor this either :(
assert isinstance(myDict, dict)
```

But to proceed on despite the risks, here's the most straightforward approach for that:

```py
x = globals()['dict']
print(x)
print(x['one'])
```

Comment: In my actual code I don't use 'dict' as the variable name I just used it for the example and forgot that it was a key word. Thank you very much this helps a lot!

Comment: No problem! glad that you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `globals` if it's a `global` variable (outside aa function):

```
print(globals()[x]['one'])
```

If it's in a function:

```
print(locals()[x]['one'])
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this instead of commenting bc I know you're not supposed to comment thanks but I don't have enough reputation to upvote so thank you very much this helped a lot!